# Erroneous reading on Non-blocking java socket client

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I have a client/server application written in Java using non-blocking IO.
There are several message types which are transferred as Json encoding and a message delimiter appended at the end of each message.
The client reads bytes and merges the messages which are coming in chunks. On regular cases it is working but in heavy load cases i get a chunk which includes messages which are not in right order. I mean, lets say I have a message m1="AAABBBCCCDDD" and m2="EEEFFF" and delimiter is "||". When the message is received it is supposed to be "AAABBBCCCDDD||EEEFFF||". But it is received "AAABBBEEEFFF||CCCDDD||". As a result it fails to parse the message.
Actually, I would like to hear the ideas that should be considered while developing network applications using non-blocking IO. what can be the reason of being in the wrong order..? 
Reader code is like this:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(20000);
count = 0;
while ((count = channel.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    buffer.flip();
    processSocketData(Charset.defaultCharset().decode(buffer));
}
```

processSocketData() method is like that:

```
socketData.append(newData);
delIndex = socketData.indexOf(cGlobals.delimiterSequence);

if (delIndex > -1) {
    processRawMessage(socketData.substring(0, delIndex));
    socketData.delete(0, delIndex + cGlobals.delimiterSize);
}
```

Comment: Without seeing a minimal code sample that replicates the problem it will be very difficult, if not impossible, to help you.

Comment: Are you using a pool of threads to read from channels? If so, you may get data out of order unless you synchronize reads and processing per channel

Answer (score 0):

You need to `flip()` before processing, as you are doing, and you also need to either `compact()` or `clear()` the buffer after you process it.